# Extract the dates on which the maximum values occured

Tags: excel

I have data consist of Day, Time and Values. I used Pivot Table to find the maximum value in each day, but I want to acquire the the time (the hour) on which that maximum occured. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Let's assume that I have the following data:

```
   A       B      C        D
  ____________________________
   Date   Time   Place    Number
1  01/01  01:00  Paris     10
2  01/01  02:00  Paris     15
3  01/01  03:00  Paris     14
4  01/01  01:00  London    13
5  01/01  02:00  London    17
6  01/01  03:00  London    19
7  02/01  01:00  Paris     10
8  02/01  02:00  Paris     15
9  02/01  03:00  Paris     14
10 02/01  01:00  London    13
11 02/01  02:00  London    17
12 02/01  03:00  London    19
```

For every place, I want to get the date and time on which the maximum value occures. So I added a new column (Named it CRITERIA) on which I applied formula: =A2&"_"&D2 (And then used autofill function). Then I created a pivot table, put CRITERIA in Rows in Number in Value, I could get the maximum value in every date, but I want to know on which hour the maximum has occured.

Thanks!

Comment: A bit more info would be helpful... see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you for notifying. Edited it.

Comment: A1 contains 01/01. And regarding the "41/1" I meant it to be "01/01". Sorry about that. I have just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have multiple maxima per `Place` I suggest in E1 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(MAX(IF(C:C=C1,D:D))=D1,"*","")
```

as an array formula (enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).